# LAMP - Multisite Platform Performance Improvements

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I'm working on a platform which is serving multiple websites for a company that currently has over 80 websites. The sites are running fine (for now) with pages appearing in less than 2-3 seconds. However the sites are growing with more viewers each day, with 1 site in particular receiving thousands of visitors daily.

I currently have the multisite structure setup using LAMP with a .htaccess file controlling requests for physical files for each site, and then a rewrite to work out which page to show depending on the host and request uri.

I haven't been in this situation before with a multisite setup all controlled by the single codebase with separate templates and separate file bases. I'm hoping someone else could advise me what I could do to improve performance before it's too late.

From my knowledge, having 80+ websites specified in the .htaccess file isn't really good for performance but I could be wrong. I assume if there is something I can do directly in the Apache vhost file that would be better for performance?

Note:
* I only use the .htaccess file to detect if a physical file exists before going to the rewrite script, to prevent PHP from handling all the file requests.

Comment: Is "hire a system administrator" to glib a comment?

Comment: Typically you want to have an Apache <VirtualHost> for each site, unless the web app you are using requires otherwise (e.g. [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)). What specific web apps are you using, and in what configurations?

Comment: The application is for not for profit organisations that require the flexibility to upload their own files in their own website's directory. Their website is built on top of a filebase that provides directories with search abilities, blogs and various other items.

I created a single filebase to minimise issues that will need to be fixed across multiple sites in the future and as a learning experiment to further my own knowledge. Plus I only wanted a single database as the parent site needs to display content from all sites on the platform.

Comment: Configuration: I've written everything from the ground up, as I'm very strict with the execution time of MySQL queries. Initially I was going to use WordPress Multisite but it just didn't cut it and the sub-sites are not blog focused. I like having complete control :)

The only additional component I've added is Smarty Templates so the organisations can use tags and cannot execute server side scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a product that used an insanely large .htaccess file as a poor man's front controller for years (not my design).  Around 700 rules in there and performance wasn't really an issue.  You are more likely to run into constraints on bandwidth to your Internet connection, your CPU, or your memory limit before this is a problem.

Is this all running on a single server?  Having 70 web sites go down when a single piece of hardware fails sounds brutal.  The first thing I would consider is setting up a second machine and wire both to some kind of shared filed system like a NAS, or consider using a service like Amazon S3 for file storage.  Put the boxes behind a load balancer so when one fails you don't have 70 angry customers.  Then when you reach 50% utilization add a third machine so a failure doesn't tip the other box over.

If that's too much administration, think about porting your solution over to something like PagodaBox.  It's cheap, it scales easily and you don't have to worry about handling the redundancies described above.

That being said, if vhosts are an option it might make more sense to organize them that way.  I just doubt it will help much with performance.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is going to be to move away from your .htaccess & put things in the apache config.  Apache configs are parsed once & remembered, while the .htaccess is read on every page load.  Either move your rewrite rules over or make some vhosts - it's not really too important which way you go.  Personally, I prefer vhosts if you're just switching on domains, saving rewrite rules for cases where URLs actually need to be manipulated.

Since you have a lot of sites with a shared core of code, an opcode cache (APC, Xcache, etc) will do wonders for performance.  It stops PHP from having to read & compile every file on every page load.  This can do amazing things for your performance, especially if you have a big chunk of 'standard' includes that aren't necessarily needed for each page.

Once you move past that, it's time to start thinking about caching queries.  Memcached can do wonders if you have a read-heavy site, and it'll scale out nicely if you ever end up going to multiple servers (as another poster mentioned, it might not be a bad idea to do so anyways, just to protect yourself from hardware failures).